# Possible data issue while retrieving a Facebook page's post comments using Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-comments, facepy

I have collected some data from a publicly available page on Facebook. I collected `Feed data using [facepy][1] via Facebook's Graph API`. I have a table(in a SQLite DB) with all comments for all posts on the Facebook page. Each tuple of that table has a `comment's comment ID` as well as the `post ID` that the comment is intended for. I later noticed that `two comments had the same comment ID` but different post ID's. I used the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to cross verify the post ID and the comment IDs. Both posts has the same set of comments however, the "link" information is different for both posts. When I checked out the actual posts that each Post JSON object represented, the set of comments that were common to both posts weren't there on the comment list for that post.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Update: I have a vague hypothesis on why this is happening. The posts that have the same comments (when queried on the Graph API Explorer) are all `photos from the same album`. It's possible that the comments are ones connected to the album's story on the page's timeline? I don't have a way to prove this though.